# How to remove user from Sharepoint Group using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-365, spuser

I want to add and remove user to/from Office 365 Group. 
I tried using C# code but got error : "User does not exist or is not unique".

After searching on the web I can't find solution.So i tried with JavaScript. I successfully add the user with JavaScript but can't removing it from office 365 group.

**Edit:** Here is my code for removing user. I have a Listbox which contains all users & I have to remove only users who exist in listbox & also in group. I am selecting Group from Dropdownlist.

```
    function removeUsers()
    {
    try {

                parm = document.getElementById('ddlGroup.id');  // ddlGroup - DropdownList to select Group
                grouptext = parm.options[parm.selectedIndex].text;
```

var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();

                visitorsGroup = groupCollection.getByName(grouptext.trim());

                selUser = document.getElementById('<%=listAllUsers.ClientID%>');  

                var listLength = selUser.options.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) 
                {

                    var usr2 = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(selUser.options[i].value);

                    var userCollection = visitorsGroup.get_users();
                    var grp, usr;
                    var isExist = false;

                    // is user exist                   
                    if(userCollection.count > 0)
                    {                        
                        for(var i=0; i < userCollection.count; i++)
                        {
                            if(userCollection[i].get_loginName() == usr2.get_loginName())
                            {
                                isExist = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (isExist == true) 
                    {                       
                            if (usr2 != null) 
                            {
                                userCollection.remove(usr2);
                                clientContext.load(userCollection);
                            }                                                       
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }
        catch (e) {            
            alert("Error in removing users:" + e.message + e.stack);
        }    

}

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("User(s) removed Successfully");
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

Comment: Showing code of what you've tried to remove a user might help

Comment: Now, I put a code above.

Answer (score 5):

The error:

> The user does not exist or is not unique

most probably occurs since user could not be found.

The list of methods that could be utilized for removing a user from group:

- [SP.UserCollection.remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245500(v=office.15).aspx)
- [SP.UserCollection.removeById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246894(v=office.15).aspx)
- [SP.UserCollection.removeByLoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245315(v=office.15).aspx)

The following examples demonstrate how to remove User from Group using [SP.UserCollection.removeByLoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245315(v=office.15).aspx)

**JSOM example**

```
function removeUserFromGroup(userLoginName,groupName,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var group = web.get_siteGroups().getByName(groupName);
    group.get_users().removeByLoginName(userLoginName); 
    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
       function(){
           success();
       },
       error);
}
```

Usage

```
var userLoginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com';
removeUserFromGroup(userLoginName,'Team Site Members',
function(){
    console.log('User has been removed from Group');
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

**REST example**

```
function removeUserFromGroup(webUrl,userLoginName,groupName)
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('" +  encodeURIComponent(groupName) + "')/users/removebyloginname(@u)?@u='" + encodeURIComponent(userLoginName) + "'";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
           "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
var userLoginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com';
var groupName = 'Team Site Members';
removeUserFromGroup(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,userLoginName,groupName)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('User has been removed from Group');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using REST**

You can `REST` endpoints for removing users from groups

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432(v=office.15).aspx#bk_UserCollectionRemoveByLoginName

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/sitegroups(7)/users
    /removebyloginname(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com'
    &@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

**Using Server Object Model**

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPGroupCollection collGroups = web.SiteGroups;
SPUserCollection usercoll = siteobj.RootWeb.SiteUsers;
int ID = oWeb.Users[UserName].ID;
usercoll.RemoveByID(ID);
web.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

**Using Client Side Object Model**

```
ClientContext client = new ClientContext(SITEURL);
client.ExecuteQuery();
Web website = client.Web;
client.Load(website, w => w.AllProperties, w => w.SiteGroups, w => w.SiteUserInfoList, w => w.Webs,w => w.Title);
client.ExecuteQuery();
GroupCollection groupCollection = website.SiteGroups;
client.Load(groupCollection, groups => groups.Include(grps => grps.Users, grps => grps.Title));
client.ExecuteQuery();
User user;
foreach (Group group in groupCollection)
{
   if (group.Title.Equals("GroupName"))
   {
        user = group.Users.GetByLoginName(“UserName”);
        group.Users.Remove(user);           
        group.Update();
        website.Update();
        client.ExecuteQuery();
        break;
    }
}
```

**Using JavaScript Object Model**

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web()
var collGroup = oWeb.get_siteGroups();
var oGroup = collGroup.getById(7); //Change 7 based on the group's id
var oUser = oGroup.get_users();
clientContext.load(oUser);
var user = web.ensureUser("domain\username);
oUser.removeByLoginName(user.get_loginName());   

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded(){
    alert('User Removed');
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Failed');
}
```