# Remove user from group Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Hi I followed another [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123448/how-to-remove-user-from-sharepoint-group-using-javascript) but cannot get the following code to work. I changed Line 8 from web to oWeb, error seems to be around line 8/9

I'm trying to remove a user from a group.

```
    function removeUserFromGroup()
    {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web()
    var collGroup = oWeb.get_siteGroups();
    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(25); //Change 7 based on the group's id
    var oUser = oGroup.get_users();
    clientContext.load(oUser);
 8)   var user = oWeb.ensureUser('DOM1\jon');

 9)   oUser.removeByLoginName(user.get_loginName());   

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded7), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed7));   

    }


    function onQuerySucceeded7(){
        alert('User Removed');
    }

    function onQueryFailed7() {
        alert('Failed');
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If I comment ensureUser ByLoginName lines it executes.

I've now change last two lines to the following and seems to work but I'd rather use Account 'domain\username'

var user = oWeb.ensureUser('Sharepoint Jon');
oUser.remove(user);

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you check if `user` is null or not?

Comment: Is the group you are trying to access readable by everyone or at least the user executing the code and is the user executing the code able to modify permissions normally?

Comment: Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a property that has not been loaded yet.  Line 9 contains `user.get_loginName()`.  Before you can use this, you need to load it first:

```
clientContext.load(user, 'Include(LoginName)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    oUser.removeByLoginName(user.get_loginName());
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded7),
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed7)
    );
}, function(args) { alert(args.get_message()); } );
```